# How to simplify jquery find and attr change for each day of the week

Tags: jquery, find, clone, attr

I don't use js/jquery that often and have got this terribly written piece of code to get my desired output.

This is required to display checkboxes properly from bulma as they don't display unless checkbox id is the same as label for and has to be unique id due to cloning.  The label field also has to follow the corresponding checkbox input otherwise it does not display and a bug occurs where only first instance of checkboxes will work.

Can someone help with simplifying the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var c=1;
$("a#ap").click(function(){
    $("product.clone").clone(false).find("#Monday, label[for='Monday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Monday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Monday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Tuesday, label[for='Tuesday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Tuesday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Tuesday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Wednesday, label[for='Wednesday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Wednesday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Wednesday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Thursday, label[for='Thursday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Thursday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Thursday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Friday, label[for='Friday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Friday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Friday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Saturday, label[for='Friday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Saturday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Saturday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("#Sunday, label[for='Sunday'] ").val("").attr({'id' : 'Sunday_'+(c), 'for' : 'Sunday_'+(c)} ).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
  c++;
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#rp").click(function () {
    if ($("product").length != 1) {
        $("product:last").remove();
    }
      //$('.clone:last').not('.clone:first').remove();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="control">
<input id="Monday_1" name="Monday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Monday_1"> <label for="Monday_1" id="Monday_1">Monday</label> 
<input id="Tuesday_1" name="Tuesday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Tuesday_1"> <label for="Tuesday_1" id="Tuesday_1">Tuesday</label> 
<input id="Wednesday_1" name="Wednesday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Wednesday_1"> <label for="Wednesday_1" id="Wednesday_1">Wednesday</label> 
<input id="Thursday_1" name="Thursday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Thursday_1"> <label for="Thursday_1" id="Thursday_1">Thursday</label> 
<input id="Friday_1" name="Friday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Friday_1"> <label for="Friday_1" id="Friday_1">Friday</label> 
<input id="Saturday_1" name="Saturday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Saturday_1"> <label for="Saturday">Saturday</label> 
<input id="Sunday_1" name="Sunday[]" type="checkbox" value="" class="is-checkradio is-white" for="Sunday_1"> <label for="Sunday_1" id="Sunday_1">Sunday</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Each chx/label pair have the same `#id` that is invalid, and the common error duplicate `#id` is usually all references stop on the first element. There are no `<a>` in HTML yet jQuery references `a#rp` and `a#ap`. BTW there are no elements like this `<product></product>` so this looks very wrong:`$("product")`.  The jQuery is a convoluted mess, I cannot fathom the purpose other than from what you said:  *"...This is required to display checkboxes properly from bulma"* but you threw me off with this `"bulma"`. If your only objective is to reveal something with checkboxes, script isn't needed.

Comment: Hey sorry zer00ne a#rp, a#ap and <product> tags are in the html just a massive chunk of code to put in so assume they work.  Duplicate Id's are not required in the label and are invalid as you say - side effect of my messy code attempt.  Bulma is a css framework https://bulma.io/ and I'm using the checkradio extension that is a pain to work with

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what OP code is supposed to do, so I made a simple calendar
with plain JavaScript.

**Details commented in Demo**

#### Demo

```js
// Define an index counter
var idx = 0;

/* Define month object
|| properties are predetermined by the month's 
|| characteristics.
*/
//* ADD/DEL extra slash at position 1
var FEB = {
  short: "FEB",
  long: "February",
  totalDays: 28,
  firstDay: 4
};

// Call genMonth(FEB) passing the FEB Object
genMonth(FEB);
//*/

/* Uncomment this and comment the FEB object */
/* This is just show that this code can accept data on any month 
|| as long as it's in the proper format.
*/

/* ADD/DEL slash at position 1
var MAY = {
  short: "MAY",
  long: "May",
  totalDays: 31,
  firstDay: 2
};

genMonth(MAY);
//*/

function genMonth(MMM) {

  // Reference table
  var month = document.querySelector('table');

  // Set table id and caption
  month.id = MMM.short;
  month.firstElementChild.setAttribute('name', MMM.long);

  // Get properties of FEB
  var dQty = MMM.totalDays;
  var xInit = MMM.firstDay;

  // First loop is for the weeks offset to 5 loops
  for (let w = 0; w < 5; w++) {

    // Each row is inserted
    var week = month.insertRow();

    // On each row an iteration for each day of the week
    for (let d = 0; d < 7; d++) {

      // if counter is more than there are days in the month...
      if (idx >= dQty) {

        // stop loop
        break;
      }

      // Insert a new cell into row
      var day = week.insertCell();

      /* if d is more or equal to the first day or...
      || it's past the 1st week
      */
      if (d >= xInit || w >= 1) {

        // Increment counter
        idx++;

        /* Insert a Template Literal into each cell.
        || Note that there are unique values for #ids 
        || interpolated in this Template Literal
        */
        day.innerHTML = `
          <sup>${idx}</sup>
           <input id='day${idx}' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
           <label for='day${idx}'></label>
           `;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 16%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.chx {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(247, 207, 89, 0.4);
  float: left;
}

label::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  content: "\f096";
}

.chx:checked+label::before {
  content: "\f046";
}

sup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

caption::after {
  content: attr(name);
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table id=''>
  <caption name=''></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SUN</th>
      <th>MON</th>
      <th>TUE</th>
      <th>WED</th>
      <th>THU</th>
      <th>FRI</th>
      <th>SAT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats really cool zer00ne - sorry for the lack of details, I've got close to what I need in my below answer however need to add an each function.

My project requires the cloning of a div containing a bunch of dropdowns and the row of checkboxes mon-sunday for each course purchased.  I needed to loop through each clone and add a count to specific ids and labels to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for one $weekday, I need to add something similar to jisaacstone last answer to this  [.each &  echo json_encode($days)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923580/jquery-inside-foreach-loop)

```
<?php foreach($days as $day){
$weekday = $day;};
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var c=1;
var day = '<?php echo $weekday ;?>';

  $("a#ap").click(function(){
  $("product.clone").clone(false)
    .find('#' + day).attr('id', day +'_' +
    (c)).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    .find("label[for='<?php echo $day; ?>']").attr('for', day + '_' +
    (c)).end().removeClass('clone').appendTo("#additional_products")
    c++;
  });
  });
</script>
```